# How is pem file base64 content padded at the end?

Tags: python, base64, rsa, padding, pem

I have to read in an RSA private key into python and get an exception "Incorrect padding" for a private key pem which should be valid.

```
rsa_p_file = open(rsa_p_filename, "r")
content = rsa_p_file.read()
rsa_p = RSA.importKey(content)
```

Now, to find the problem I experimented with another pem file for which it works. This pem file ends with

```
8YPmbfUbUcCj6CQfIcSZcg==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

To my knowledge the = at the end are padding bytes to make the total length of the base64 a multiple of 4. In this case the total length is 1624, so it is OK.

However, when I remove the last "g" and replace it by "="

```
8YPmbfUbUcCj6CQfIcSZc===
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

It gives excpeption:

```
Error: Incorrect padding
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 204, in t1_process
    meters = extract.parseShipmentFile(ifile, pkpath, serials)
  File "D:\Siemens\Projects\DLMS_becom\code\python\shipment\extract.py", line 146, in parseShipmentFile
    rsa_p = RSA.importKey(content)
  File "C:\Users\atw11a92\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 736, in import_key
    (der, marker, enc_flag) = PEM.decode(tostr(extern_key), passphrase)
  File "C:\Users\atw11a92\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\IO\PEM.py", line 168, in decode
    data = a2b_base64(b(''.join(lines[1:-1])))
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Why is padding still incorrect, because total length%4 is 0 again ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding

Comment: Base64 padding is either one or two "=" characters, not three. See the link in the comment by James.

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky, you can have access to the source of a2b_base64 on git:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/base64.py

And you can see that the error "Incorrect padding" is raised from 2 points:

```
s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
if len(s) % 8:
    raise binascii.Error('Incorrect padding')
```

Here it checks if your string's size is a multiple of 8, not 4.

You have also other checks on the padding characters:

```
l = len(s)
s = s.rstrip(b'=')
padchars = l - len(s)
(...)

if padchars:
    acc <<= 5 * padchars
    last = acc.to_bytes(5, 'big')
    if padchars == 1:
        decoded[-5:] = last[:-1]
    elif padchars == 3:
        decoded[-5:] = last[:-2]
    elif padchars == 4:
        decoded[-5:] = last[:-3]
    elif padchars == 6:
        decoded[-5:] = last[:-4]
    else:
        raise binascii.Error('Incorrect padding')
return bytes(decoded)
```

But this other part would need a bit of investigation to understand better its behaviour.

I hope this help!